# Python strip() not working inside a function

Tags: python, string, strip

I am trying to use `strip()` to trim off the space before and after a string. It works fine for

```
str1 = "  abdced "
str1.strip()
```

However when I use it inside a function, it is not working:

```
def func(str1):
    return str1.strip() 

print func("   abdwe ")
```

It won't trim off any space. Anyone can tell what's happening? Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it work for the second, not the first?

Comment: `def func(str1): return str1.strip()`    `assert func("   abcd  ") == "abcd"` -  not reproducible.

Comment: Basic rule of Python strings - you can't alter them, you can only create new ones (they are *immutable*)

Answer (score 8):

`strip` is not an in-place method, meaning it returns a value which must be reassigned like so:

```
str1 = str1.strip() # the string is reassigned to the returned stripped string
```

Comment: The function does return the new value, so IMHO this isn't the explanation of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Three things I see.

First, you are not assigning the strip variable to anything, second you are trying to do this in a return.

The return should only have the variables you wish to return to be used in another function. You can print from this function, but your return statement should not have any activity, only the variable to be returned.

Third, that print statement looks off to me. At the very least it isn't how I would do the print.

```
def func(str1):
    str1 = "  abdced "

    str2 = str1.strip()

    print(str2)

    return str1, str2
```